# Append string to list contained in dictionary value in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary that looks something like this (but much bigger):

```
my_dict:
  "id1": "name1"
  "id2": "name2"
  "id3": "name1"
  "id4": "name2"
  "id5": "name1"
  "id6": "name3"
```

In Ansible, how can I create a task(s) that "inverts" this dictionary to look like this:

```
result_dict:
  "name1": ["id1", "id3", "id5"]
  "name2": ["id2", "id4"]
  "name3": ["id6"]
```

I've tried this:

```
- name: "Get list of unique ids"
  set_fact:
    unique_names: "{{ my_dict.values() | unique }}"

- name: "Initialize result_dict with empty lists"
  set_fact:
    result_dict: "{{ result_dict | combine(item: []) }}"
  loop: "{{ unique_names }}"

- name: "Populate result_dict lists"
  set_fact:
    result_dict: "{{ result_dict | combine(new_item, recursive=true)}}"
  vars:
    new_item: "{ '{{ item.value }}': { item.value: item.key } }"
  with_dict: "{{ result_dict }}"
  loop: "{{ my_dict | dict2items }}"
```

I'm fairly new to Ansible. The issue is that I'm not sure how to append to the list that is already there. Hopefully that makes sense. Is there a better way to go about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options:

- **Jinja**

The simplest option is [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#). For example, the expression below

```yaml
  result: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in my_dict|dict2items|groupby('value') %}
    {{ i.0 }}: {{ i.1|map(attribute='value') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  result:
    name1: [id1, id3, id5]
    name2: [id2, id4]
    name3: [id6]
```

---

- **community.general.lists_mergeby**

Use the filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries). Convert the dictionary to a list and put the attribute key into the list too

```yaml
  list1: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|
             json_query('[].{key: [key], value: value}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list1:
    - key: [id1]
      value: name1
    - key: [id2]
      value: name2
    - key: [id3]
      value: name1
    - key: [id4]
      value: name2
    - key: [id5]
      value: name1
    - key: [id6]
      value: name3
```

Merge the items by *value* and append the lists

```yaml
  merge: "{{ [list1, []]|
             community.general.lists_mergeby('value', list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  merge:
    - key: [id1, id3, id5]
      value: name1
    - key: [id2, id4]
      value: name2
    - key: [id6]
      value: name3
```

Convert the list to a dictionary. Either use the intermediate result *merge* or add the filter *items2dict* to the pipe

```yaml
  result: "{{ [list1, []]|
              community.general.lists_mergeby('value', list_merge='append')|
              items2dict(key_name='value', value_name='key') }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  result:
    name1: [id1, id3, id5]
    name2: [id2, id4]
    name3: [id6]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_dict:
      id1: name1
      id2: name2
      id3: name1
      id4: name2
      id5: name1
      id6: name3

    list1: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|
               json_query('[].{key: [key], value: value}') }}"
    merge: "{{ [list1, []]|
               community.general.lists_mergeby('value', list_merge='append') }}"
    result: "{{ [list1, []]|
                community.general.lists_mergeby('value', list_merge='append')|
                items2dict(key_name='value', value_name='key') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list1|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: merge|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

---

- **dict(keys|zip(values))**

In this option, get the keys and values and use the function [dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data) to create the dictionary.

Convert the dictionary to a list and group the items by value

```yaml
  _grps: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|groupby('value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _grps:
    - - name1
      - - {key: id1, value: name1}
        - {key: id3, value: name1}
        - {key: id5, value: name1}
    - - name2
      - - {key: id2, value: name2}
        - {key: id4, value: name2}
    - - name3
      - - {key: id6, value: name3}
```

Get the keys

```yaml
  _keys: "{{ _grps|map('first') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _keys: [name1, name2, name3]
```

Get the values

```yaml
  _vals: "{{ _grps|map('last')|map('map', attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _vals:
    - [id1, id3, id5]
    - [id2, id4]
    - [id6]
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  result: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  result:
    name1: [id1, id3, id5]
    name2: [id2, id4]
    name3: [id6]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_dict:
      id1: name1
      id2: name2
      id3: name1
      id4: name2
      id5: name1
      id6: name3

    _grps: "{{ my_dict|dict2items|groupby('value') }}"
    _keys: "{{ _grps|map('first') }}"
    _vals: "{{ _grps|map('last')|map('map', attribute='key') }}"
    result: "{{ dict(_keys|zip(_vals)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: _grps|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: _keys|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: _vals|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to tackle this. Fundamentally, Ansible by itself isn't a great choice for *manipulating* your data; you're often better off [writing a custom filter plugin](https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2019-04-25-writing-ansible-filter-plugins/) and implementing your logic in Python.

For example, if I place the following code in `filter_plugins/group_by_value.py`:

```
import itertools


def group_by_value(val):
    return [
        (k, [x for x, y in v])
        for k, v in itertools.groupby(
            sorted(val.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[1]
        )
    ]


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            "group_by_value": group_by_value,
        }
```

Then I can write a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_dict:
      "id1": "name1"
      "id2": "name2"
      "id3": "name1"
      "id4": "name2"
      "id5": "name1"
      "id6": "name3"
  tasks:
    - name: Populate result_dict
      set_fact:
        result_dict: "{{ my_dict | group_by_value }}"

    - debug:
        var: result_dict
```

And get this output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result_dict": [
        [
            "name1",
            [
                "id1",
                "id3",
                "id5"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "name2",
            [
                "id2",
                "id4"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "name3",
            [
                "id6"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I think that implementing the logic in a filter plugin results in much more obvious logic and cleaner playbooks/vars files.